# android firebase crashlytics invalid key error

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

I integrated firebase crashlytics using below url and it was working fine.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0

Then I did git pull from other developer and went to build project and got following error:

Error:org.gradle.api.GradleException: Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
Error:com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.PluginException: Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null.

Comment: I had the same issue today, it was working fine for a month and then suddenly stopped working. Did you find a reason behind it?

Comment: same issue here, any resolution on your end?

Comment: I had same issue.....ended up initializing manually (instead of using plugin) and it worked then (might also be related to fact that I'm also initialising Firebase manually).

Answer (score 0):

I have added this line in end of `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Firebase Crashlytics requires the Google services Gradle plugin (com.google.gms:google-services) in your build script to process the google-services.json file at build time. However, Crashlytics does work on devices that do not have Google Play services.

Answer (score -3):

Firstly, You must add firebase into your project as https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0